# Binding content list to ComboBox in WPF MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, combobox, binding

So let me preface by saying that I am very new to WPF and MVVM.

I am using the mvvm design pattern for my application. My goal, is that I need to have two combo boxes loaded with content to select from( in this case, units to convert from and to). The content of these combo boxes is determined by a third combo box which determines the type of units to load.

So for example, the first combo box would let the user select a unit type, such as speed or temperature.  So if I select temperature, the other two combo boxes would be loaded with a list of temperature units. Likewise if I select speed, then the list in the other two combo boxes would be replaced with units for speed.

I already have a class that handles the from and to conversion. But I'm a little lost with how to start working with these combo boxes. I have only done some basic things with combo boxes like loading content straight in the xaml. I have seen people make lists and somehow bind them but some it was a little overwhelming.

All I need is a good example and explanation to get me started. Would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: check out the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62408903/10024696).

Answer (score 0):

Everything you need is a ViewModel class to work with the binding.

Each combo box will binding the ItemSources to a Property in the ViewModel. Everytime the selected of the first combo box is change, you will update the data source of the second combo box.

Here is example of the ViewModel class:

```
    namespace WpfApp1
    {
        class SampleVM : ViewModelBase
        {
            private ObservableCollection<UnitEntry> _comboBox1ItemSource;
            private ObservableCollection<TypeEntry> _comboBoxTypeItemSource;
            private int _selectedTypeIndex;
    
            public ObservableCollection<UnitEntry> ComboBoxUnitItemSource
            {
                get => _comboBox1ItemSource;
                set
                {
                    _comboBox1ItemSource = value;
                    RaisePropertyChange(nameof(ComboBoxUnitItemSource));
                }
            }
    
            public ObservableCollection<TypeEntry> ComboBoxTypeItemSource
            {
                get => _comboBoxTypeItemSource;
                set
                {
                    _comboBoxTypeItemSource = value;
                    RaisePropertyChange(nameof(ComboBoxTypeItemSource));
                }
            }
    
            public int SelectedTypeIndex
            { 
                get => _selectedTypeIndex;
                set
                {
                    _selectedTypeIndex = value;
                    RaisePropertyChange(nameof(SelectedTypeIndex));
    
                    //Here where we will handle the data in the second combo box depend on the Type value when it changed
                    if(value == 0)
                    {
                        ComboBoxUnitItemSource = GetDataUnitType1();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ComboBoxUnitItemSource = GetDataUnitType2();
                    }
                }
            }
    
            public SampleVM()
            {
                InitData();
            }
    
            private void InitData()
            {
                //Init Type data
                ComboBoxTypeItemSource = new ObservableCollection<TypeEntry>();
    
                TypeEntry type1 = new TypeEntry(0, "Type 1");
    
                TypeEntry type2 = new TypeEntry(1, "Type 2");
    
                ComboBoxTypeItemSource.Add(type1);
                ComboBoxTypeItemSource.Add(type2);
    
                //Selected Index set to default by 0
                SelectedTypeIndex = 0;
            }
    
            private ObservableCollection<UnitEntry> GetDataUnitType1()
            {
//Get your real data instead of fake data below
                ObservableCollection<UnitEntry> data = new ObservableCollection<UnitEntry>();
    
                for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
                {
                    UnitEntry unitEntry = new UnitEntry(i, $"Type 1 - Entry: {i}");
                    data.Add(unitEntry);
                }
    
                return data;
            }
    
            private ObservableCollection<UnitEntry> GetDataUnitType2()
            {
//Get your real data instead of fake data below
                ObservableCollection<UnitEntry> data = new ObservableCollection<UnitEntry>();
    
                for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
                {
                    UnitEntry unitEntry = new UnitEntry(i, $"Type 2 - Entry: {i}");
                    data.Add(unitEntry);
                }
    
                return data;
            }
        }
    
        public class TypeEntry
        {
            public int ID { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
    
            public TypeEntry(int id, string name)
            {
                ID = id;
                Name = name;
            }
        }
    
        public class UnitEntry
        {
            public int ID { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
    
            public UnitEntry(int id, string name)
            {
                ID = id;
                Name = name;
            }
        }
    }
```

And here is the xaml class looks like:

```
<!-- The "Name" value is the Name property in the Entry class-->
        <ComboBox Grid.Row="0"
                  Grid.Column="0" 
                  Width="200"
                  Height="30"
                  DisplayMemberPath="Name" 
                  SelectedValuePath="Name"
                  SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedTypeIndex}"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding ComboBoxTypeItemSource}"/>

        <ComboBox Grid.Row="0"
                  Grid.Column="1"
                  Width="200"
                  Height="30"
                  DisplayMemberPath="Name"
                  SelectedValuePath="Name"
                  SelectedIndex="0"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding ComboBoxUnitItemSource}"/>
```

Finally, important part, you need to assign the ViewModel to the View class:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = new SampleVM();
        }
    }
```